# Apache Poi - Algo 

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working on to fetch data from database and show on excel. I am using Apache poi library to generate excel.

here's the snippet for generating excel.

```
public class GenerateReport {

    public void showReport() {

    List<T> t = sampleDao.getAllData();


    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    HSSFRow row     = null;
        HSSFCell column = null;

        HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(1);

        HSSFCell c11 = row1.createCell(1);
        HSSFCell c12 = row1.createCell(2);
        HSSFCell c13 = row1.createCell(3);
        HSSFCell c14 = row1.createCell(4);
        HSSFCell c15 = row1.createCell(5);

        c11.setCellValue("ID");
        c12.setCellValue("Date");
        c13.setCellValue("Time");
        c14.setCellValue("YES/NO");
        c15.setCellValue("Action");



for (final T sampleT: t) {

            ....algo and what should be written 

         }


    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=\"Sample Report");
    workbook.write(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());
    facesContext.responseComplete();

    }
    }
```

//getter setter for DAO

```
public void setSampleDao(
                SampleDao sampleDao) {
            this.sampleDao = sampleDao;
        }

        public SampleDao getSampleDao() {
            return sampleDao;
        }

    }


sampleDao.getAllData();
```

getAllData() method returns data which needs to be displayed via query.

I need help how to get data and what should be written in this for loop

```
for (final T sampleT: t) {

                ....algo and what should be written 

             }
```

There's a condition that if  c14.setCellValue("YES/NO"); is Yes, then under this cell      c15.setCellValue("Action"), a particular action is to be written.

---

ID          Date            Time             YES/NO         Action

---

Yes/No data is coming from database (sampleDao.getAllData();) , if Yes is present then i will have write a particular action in Action Column, after fetching the second data, it will check the previous Yes/No, if both are same/ or changed, i need to write Action according to it.

Can somebody help me

1. in writing snippet in for loop with conditions.
2. and how to set data in cells.

Answer (score 2):

When you have written so much, I fail to understand why its difficult to fill up the loop.

Here's the algorithm/pseudo code...

```
String previousYesNo=null":
int rowcounter=2;
for (final T sampleT: t) {
  create hssf row with rowcounter
  create hssf cell for the 5 columns
  set data to all the columns from the sampleT object
  String yesNo=sampleT.getYesNO();
  if(previousYesNo!=null && prviousYesNo.equals(yesNo)){
    set action cell value to something
  }else{
    set action cell value to something else
  }
  previousYesNo=yesNo;
  rowCounter++;
}
```

To set data in cells:

```
HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIdx);
HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(colIdx);
//if its a string.. otherwise choose the correct cell type
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell..CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set data in cell like this

`

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(excelColNum);
            if (cell == null) {
    cell = row.createCell(excelColNum);
}
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue( cellValue);
```

`